# Compare two JSONObject values and if true than display it

Tags: android, arrays, json

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oCf8o.png)

I want to compare the JSONObject "day1" and "day2".
if it match then display it. 
how to do it,

somebody tell me please ......

Comment: Some idea? compare the JSONObject "day1" and "day2". if it match then display it. Please visit the help center and take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see what to ask and how.

Comment: chauhan saab parse json to get both values and compare days (timestamp)

Answer (score 2):

First I would put the data into [POJO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_Java_Object) object.
I recommend using [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson) for this part.

Then you create a [Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) object and use to compare all your newly created objects.

```
public class Day implements Comparator<Day> {

    private String someProperty;

    public String getSomeProperty() {
         return someProperty;
    }

    public void setSomeProperty(String someProperty) {
        this.someProperty = someProperty;
    }
   // Overriding the compare method to sort the age 
   public int compare(Day d1, Day d2){
      return d1.getSomeProperty().compare(d2.getSomeProperty());
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

More simple way, but not cool. (Michael B. way better)

```
        Iterator<String> it = jsonObject1.keys();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            String key = it.next();
            if (jsonOject1.optString(key).equals(jsonObject2.optString(key))) {
                //print what u need
            }
        }
```

Comment: @Nikhilchauhan firstly you take all names of fields in your First JSONObject, then you check is values in that fields are equal. So you can copy and paste that code and put there your JSONObject variables.

Comment: @MichaelB. thats why I said that your way better, but not for unskilled person :)